# Matplotlib how to add line to stock price chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have a closing price stock chart, now i want to add a line at certain date, 2015-12-01, pls let me know how to do it. Here is my existing code. For prices I am using Pandas

```
data = pd.DataFrame(sp['Close'], index=sp.index)

line = plt.subplot(2015-07-01, 2015-07-01, 'b-')

data.plot()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just

l = plt.axvline(date(2015,2,16) linewidth=1)